# Facebook php sdk getuser() not working on the web only on my localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

so i did a web app with php facebook sdk and run it on my localhost...
everything seems to be fine, the function GetUser got me the user id...
then when i upload the web to the a host server GetUser() return always 0...
is somebody figure it out?

this is my code, nothing special:

```
$homeurl = 'http://postmaster.net78.net/MainMenu.php';  //return to home
$fbPermissions = 'user_events,friends_events,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access';       
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '****', 
  'secret' => '***', 
));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    echo $user;
if ($user) 
{
  .......
}
else 
{
    
  $_fb['loginurl'] = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope' => $fbPermissions));
  $_fb['authed'] = false;
  echo '<center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>For start working with <img src="images/logoBlack.gif" height = "8%" width="15%">  <br>you must connect to your facebook account<br>';
  echo '<a href="'.$_fb['loginurl'].'"><img src="images/loginwithfacebook.jpg"></a>';
}
```

and my developer info:
[image]

thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. In my case it had to do with cURL and SSL certificate.

I am still trying to figure out why it has no problems on my localhost, I am thinking it could be cURL or SSL settings at my Webhost.

In the meantime A quick fix is to tell cURL to accept any SSL certificate.

**Add this to your base_facebook.php file:**

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
```

Place it right before `$result = curl_exec($ch);`

From a security point of view it is probably not the best solution but if it works for you it should give you a starting point to find a permanent fix.

See this page for more insight: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/